# Anomalous behavior in MPI execution time

Tags: performance, mpi, cluster-computing

When I run a N copies of the same job on N different nodes, to which I have exclusive access, with MPI and I get different execution time every time for all the processes to finish, what do you think is the most probable reason ? The difference in execution time every run can be as high as 100% ! The processes does the same thing every run, there is no random element that can make the execution time vary from run to run.

Comment: Two questions: Are you sure you are not calling MPI_Wtime before MPI_Init (assuming you are timing that way)? Also have you tried to insert an initial MPI_Barrier just before you start timing to exclude process creation and such?

Comment: I am timing between two points in the program using clock_gettime and that's after the MPI initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem comes from the scheduling issues between [your MPI based process and the MPI thread within your process] and other proccesses.

One good tried and tested solution to make it real time :

1. Enforce CPU affinity on your MPI receiver Thread that processes the incoming data and/or command(JOb).
2. Make sure that There are less(no) non-useful processes (apart from your MPI based application ) running on all of your nodes.  This will reduce the other processes steping on your your MPI based Application's cpu time chunk.